# Error in ruby script while running meterpreter

Tags: ruby, metasploit

I love this website, it has helped me a lot through other people's questions, now I have joined so I can help each others if I can.

I have an issue here.
While running meterpreter (from metasploit suite) in a VM, I have tried a script that relays all the ports in the compromised machine and creates a virtual interface in your local machine. But I'm getting the error

`Undefined method: each`.

While going to the code:

```
def discovery()
  ip_port = []
  # Alive hosts discovery
  temphosts = []
  hosts = []
  ## oldstdout = $stdout ## Trick for capturing stdout
  $stdout = StringIO.new
  client.run_cmd('run landiscovery')
  temphosts = $stdout.string
  $stdout = oldstdout
  print_status "Alive Hosts:"
  temphosts.each do |x|
    if x.match(/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/)
      y = x.chomp
      hosts << y
      print " - #{y}\n"
    end
  end
end
```

I think it is somehow related to the line I have surrounded with `##`. It has to be `nil` so `temphosts` is `nil` too and I get the each error.

Can someone point me in a good direction?

Thanks greatly appreciated.

PS: The scripts if someone is interested are in here: http://tools.pentester.es/multirelay

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
$stdout.string
```

This line will return a single String object, containing all the lines of your output, with \n characters included.
String objects do not have any each method.

Maybe you wanted to get a list of Strings, representing the list of lines of your output. In this case, you should first split your String:

```
temphosts.split("\n").each do |x|
```